# HibernateTemplate.save() method is not inserting in DB

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. I am just trying to insert a new record in my table using Hibernate Spring Integration. Please see below code

My beans.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="mainClient" class="Client.MainClient">
    <property name="contactDetailsDao" ref="contactDetailsBean"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="contactDetailsBean" class="DAO.ContactDetailsDAO">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplateBean"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean"></property>
    <property name="checkWriteOperations" value="false"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"></property>
    <property name="mappingResources" value="ContactDetails.xml"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/SpringLearnDatabase"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

My hibernate.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ContactDetailsDTO.ContactDetailsDTO" table="contactDetails">
    <id name="contactId" column="id" type="string"></id>
    <property name="name" column="Name" type="string"></property>
    <property name="mobileNumber" column="MobileNumber" type="string"></property>
    <property name="emailId" column="EmailId" type="string"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My DAO class :

```
package DAO;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

import ContactDetailsDTO.ContactDetailsDTO;

public class ContactDetailsDAO {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }

    public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }

    public void insertIntoContact(ContactDetailsDTO cd){
        try{
            hibernateTemplate.save(cd);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<ContactDetailsDTO> getAllAccounts(){
        return (List<ContactDetailsDTO>) hibernateTemplate.find("from ContactDetailsDTO");
    }

}
```

When I try to getAllAccounts I can see select query in console and records from table, but when I try to insert new record in table, insert query is not displayed on console and new record is not inserted in table.

save() method is not inserting new record. Please check where I am wrong and reply

Thanks

Comment: You definitely have a problem with naming convention. Packages must be lowercase. What is the ContactDetailsDTO? What is Db table for the entity? How id should be filled? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I am not getting any error on console. Just insertion is not working